# Truffle Console Script giving Error: Cannot find module

Tags: truffle-console

I am trying to run the following script:

```
const messageBuild = require('./build/contracts/MyContract.json')

const MyContract = require('~/Truffle_programs/script_transfer_Eth_thr_Truffle/contracts/MyContract.sol');
const MyContractTester = require('~/Truffle_programs/script_transfer_Eth_thr_Truffle/contracts/MyContractTester.sol');
module.exports = (callback)=>{
var acc1 = accounts[1]
var acc2 = accounts[2]
const myC = MyContract.deployed()
const myCT =  MyContractTester.deployed()
web3.eth.sendTransaction({to:myC.address, from:acc2, value: web3.utils.toWei('11')})
balance2 =  web3.eth.getBalance(acc2)
web3.utils.fromWei(balance2, "ether")
mybal = web3.eth.getBalance(myC.address)
web3.utils.fromWei(mybal, "ether")
myC.sendTo(myCT.address, web3.utils.toWei('3',"ether"), {from:accounts[0]})
myCbal = web3.eth.getBalance(myC.address)
web3.utils.fromWei(myCbal, "ether")
myCTbal = web3.eth.getBalance(myCT.address)
web3.utils.fromWei(myCTbal, "ether")
}
```

but I am getting the error:

```
truffle(development)> truffle exec ./myscript.js
Using network 'development'.

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^
Error: Cannot find module '~/Truffle_programs/script_transfer_Eth_thr_Truffle/contracts/MyContract.sol'
```

I tried the "ls" command and found that the path is correct:

```
@lc2530hz:~$ ls ~/Truffle_programs/script_transfer_Eth_thr_Truffle/contracts/
Migrations.sol  MyContract.sol  MyContractTester.sol
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.